# Android Room append String to Select columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, case, android-room

In my table, I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "species" (
    "_id"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "name_es"   TEXT,
    "name_it"   TEXT,
    "name_fr"   TEXT,
    "name_de"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("_id")
);
```

As you can see, my "name" column is localized in multiple languages appending the _isocode at the end.

I'm trying to figure out how can I manipulate the DAO query in order to append the lang parameter in the Select itself, something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT name " + lang +
        " FROM species")
List<SpeciesEntity> getSpecies(String lang);
```

But It simply doesn't work (it doesn't even compile) , I've also tried using the SQLITE concat `||` like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT name||:lang " +
        " FROM species")
List<SpeciesEntity> getSpecies(String lang);
```

But it doesn't work either, it only appends the `_es` isocode to the actual `name` column value instead of retrieving the `name_es` column value. Is there any way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support dynamic sql, so that you can't create dynamically the name of the column.

What you can do is use a `CASE` expression to check the value `:lang` and return the column that you should select:

```
SELECT CASE :lang
         WHEN '_es' THEN name_es
         WHEN '_it' THEN name_it
         WHEN '_fr' THEN name_fr
         WHEN '_de' THEN name_de
         ELSE name
       END AS my_name
FROM species
```

I assume that `:lang` is a string starting with `_`, like `_xx`.